# glass shader material

Tags: glass

Any Idea why I am getting weird result in the render for glass material?

I tried with the principled shader (transmittion to zero and roughness to zero) and glass shader.

scale in 1 and face orientation is correct.

The glass object is made with two planes (with thickness, air in between) but I tried deleting the one face and makeing it only a singluar plane but no difference.

Any idea?[image]

Comment: By weird result you mean this repetition? Could you please share your file?

Comment: yes, the repetition. It doesn't look realistic at all. Here is the model: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=V11EOymw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/V11EOymw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a (curious) surface shading effect.

Use shade flat instead of smooth.

Comment: So the problem turned out to be glass cuboids looking like glass cylinders?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady something like that, I think